# Weird jQuery .post behavior

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have several clones of this script throughout my site and they work. The function is to enable liking, following, etc. (anything that requires a reference table to store the like, follows, etc.) The problem is with my liking function its running the .post 12 times. My follow script has the same jquery code but doesn't do this. So I resorted to checking my fave.php/unfave.php files, but I can't find any errors. Its the same as my follow.php/unfollow.php files. Can anyone spot or realize this odd behavior?

Basically I'm getting 12 entries into my DB. Why?

fave.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){   
    $(".fvspan").on("click", ".favebtn", function(){
    var fvs = $(this).attr('id');
        if(fvs)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mobile/inc/vdfave.php",
                data: "fvs=" + fvs, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("span#" + fvs + ".fvspan").html("<img id='" + fvs + "' class='favebtn-un' src='/assets/faved.png' height='50px'>");
                }
            });
        }
        else { }                    
    }); 
});

$(function(){   
    $(".fvspan").on("click", ".favebtn-un", function(){
    var fvs = $(this).attr('id');

        if(fvs)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mobile/inc/vdunfave.php",
                data: "fvs=" + fvs, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){                    
                    $("span#" + fvs + ".fvspan").html("<img id='" + fvs + "' class='favebtn' src='/assets/fave.png' height='50px'>");
                }
            });
        }
        else { }

    }); 
}); 
   });
```

vdfave.php

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

    //Make an SQL connection
    include('/home/bfreak/www/inc/dbc.php');

    $myself = $_SESSION['username'];
    $ref = $_POST['fvs'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {    }
    else{$myinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myself'");}

while($myid1 = mysql_fetch_array($myinfo)) 
{ 
    $myid = $myid1['id']; 

    //Insert form data into database with corresponding structure, in respective order, of SQL columns.
    $fvd = "INSERT INTO faves (vid, usr, date) VALUES ('$ref', '$myid', '$date')";
    if (!mysql_query($fvd, $con))   {die('Fatal Error: ' . mysql_error());}
}

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: you have nested "document ready"s. Can you remove `$(document).ready(function(){` from first line and check again?

Comment: `mysql_` functions? No... no...

Comment: I think I figured it with some logic. There's multiple .favebtn's onda page. Now I have to figure a solution that make $(this) refer to the item's unique id.

Comment: What I decided to do was remove liking and commenting off of the feed pages and leave them on the unique pages. Im handling videos anyway so why would someone want to comment or like something they haven't seen yet. You'll still be able to click the report button from the feed pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have duplicate usernames in `users` table in database. `while` loop may be running 12 times.

Change this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myself'");
```

to following:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myself' LIMIT 1");
```

and check again.

Comment: I figured it with some logic. There's multiple .favebtn's onda page. Now I have to figure a solution that make $(this) refer to the item's unique id. When I go to the item's unique page there's only one .favebtn so it inputs only once. Tested+Approved

Comment: I tried your JS code myself, it behaves okay. Could you add your HTML code here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! i ran the js script in the loop. I took it out and it works!